# Failed to build gem native extension ruby 2.0 upgrade fastthread

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.0

I am upgrading my system to ruby 2.0 and I have done everything short of throw my computer on the wall. I find it hard to believe that fastthread is the problem. Has anyone else seen this error when running 'bundle install'. Here is my ruby version

ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

when I try to run rails -v I get this

rails -v
Could not find fastthread-1.0.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.6.1) 
Using activesupport (3.2.9) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.9) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.9) 
Using mime-types (1.21) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.9) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.9) 
Using activeresource (3.2.9) 
Using bundler (1.3.0) 
Using highline (1.6.15) 
Using net-ssh (2.6.5) 
Using net-scp (1.1.0) 
Using net-sftp (2.1.1) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0) 
Using capistrano (2.14.2) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.7) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.5.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.7.7) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.17.0) 
Using railties (3.2.9) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using fssm (0.2.10) 
Using sass (3.2.6) 
Using compass (0.12.2) 
Using compass-rails (1.0.3) 
Using daemon_controller (1.1.1) 
Installing fastthread (1.0.7) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

make
Makefile:104: *** missing separator.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing fastthread (1.0.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install fastthread -v '1.0.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Has anyone else ran into this?

Conents of  /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_mak‌​e.out

```
/Users/[me]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb

extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated   Config.

make
Makefile:104: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Comment: And what does /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_make.out
 look like?

Comment: Thank you for looking at it Casper, and I have updated the topic with the contents of that gem_make.out file. I have also inspected the ruby extconf.rb file and it is random characters.

Comment: That's a really old gem. Are you sure you need it? I don't think you do(?) I would remove it from the dependencies and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely do not, but it was in the gemfile.lock and I deleted  that file because it was causing me errors. Maybe I just need to add that file again and bundle it again.

Comment: No it won't work. Config is deprecated in Ruby 2.0 as far as I could make out. You have to upgrade your dependencies or file a bug report on the gem that is requiring fastthread as a dependency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phusion Passenger 4 has already solved this by removing the fastthread dependency. The 4.0 betas and RCs install just fine on Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Exactly. Just install the newest version of Passenger (`gem install passenger -v 4.0.0.rc4`).

Comment: for anyone operating on Snow Leopard highest passenger version applicable is 4.0.5

Answer (score 3):

If you use Passenger as your webserver you *have* to have this dependency.  See this pull request for the fix:  https://github.com/zoltankiss/fastthread/commit/a47a121990cf7d4f31147406c2d379dabc048479

The author of the gem has not yet included this fix.  You can require fastthread from https://github.com/zoltankiss/fastthread if you need it.  That is who submitted the pull request.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think it's needed for Ruby >= 1.9 any more, even if using Passenger. See this blog post here: http://blog.phusion.nl/2009/02/02/getting-ready-for-ruby-191/ , and this github issue: https://github.com/mental/fastthread/issues/2 . I don't use passenger so I may be wrong, but the blog post does say fastthread is a no-op in Ruby 1.9..

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this. This was the problem. I removed the passenger gem (which was the one creating the dependency problem, apparently) and I can now make everything work. Now I know how to fix it! Thank you Casper and LRH!

Comment: @Casper I'm pretty sure.  https://rubygems.org/gems/passenger The passenger gem still lists fastthread as a runtime dependency.  Whether its a no-op or not it must compile correctly to install passenger.

Comment: @LRH - Ok thx. Good to know. And the fix is easy to apply anyway.

Comment: The author of this gem looks to be inactive. We might have to create a fork and apply the pull request ourselves and notify passenger to point to the new one.